# Why is my chat filter blocking the word on the top of the wod list? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

My chat filter is only filtering the word on the top of the list, and I'm not sure why. Can anyone fix this?

```
with open("badwords.txt") as file:
    bad_words = file.read().splitlines()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):    
    for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in message.content.lower().split(" "):
            t = discord.Embed(color=0x039e00, title="Message Removed", description=f":x:   Please don't say that here, {message.author.mention}.")
            t.set_footer(text="DM TheSuperRobert2498#2498 for bot suggestions.")
            await message.channel.send(embed=t, delete_after=5)
            await message.delete()
        else:
            await client.process_commands(message)
            return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exiting when the first word is not in the the list with the `return` keyword, simply delete it and everything should work. Also the `process_commands` should be outside that else statement

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):    
    for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in message.content.lower().split(" "):
            t = discord.Embed(color=0x039e00, title="Message Removed", description=f":x:   Please don't say that here, {message.author.mention}.")
            t.set_footer(text="DM TheSuperRobert2498#2498 for bot suggestions.")
            await message.channel.send(embed=t, delete_after=5)
            await message.delete()

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

If you want a bit of a shorter way you can use the `any` function

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):    
    if any(bad_word in message.content.lower() for bad_word in bad_words):
        t = discord.Embed(color=0x039e00, title="Message Removed", description=f":x:   Please don't say that here, {message.author.mention}.")
        t.set_footer(text="DM TheSuperRobert2498#2498 for bot suggestions.")
        await message.channel.send(embed=t, delete_after=5)
        await message.delete()

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it.

Comment: Happy to help, remember to accept the answer!